# How to add a new element y after the first occurrence of x (linear linked list) C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hello everyone :) Kind of new to all these so excuse me if I'm doing something wrong.
I'm currently doing an assignment and I've been stuck on this part for quite a while. What I want to do is to add a new element 'y' after the first occurrence of element 'x' on the insert function(int x, int y) in linear linked list, which uses dynamic allocation of memory for its nodes.
Would gladly appreciate any advice. Thank you for your time :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node {
    int value;
    node* next;
};
node* list = NULL;
node* first_item = new node();
void print() { 

    node* iterator = list;
    if (iterator == NULL) {
        cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
    }
    while (iterator != NULL)
    {
        cout << iterator->value; // print node value
        if (iterator->next != NULL) {
            cout << " -> ";
        }
        iterator = iterator->next; // progress to next value
    }

    cout << endl;
}
void insert(int y) { // adds a new element y as the first element in the list

    first_item->value = y;
    list = first_item; // point list to first item

}
void insert(int x, int y) {  // adds a new element y after the first occurrence of element x


    first_item->value = x;
    node* second_item = new node(); // a second item
    second_item->value = y;
    second_item->next = first_item->next;
    list->next = second_item;

}

int main()
{
    node* list = NULL;
    print();
    insert(0);
    print();
    insert(0, 1); 

    print();
    insert(1, 3);
    print();
    insert(1, 2);
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

My false output value that i get:

```
    EMPTY

    0 
    0 -> 1
    1 -> 3 -> 1
    1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1
```

And the right value that I need:

```
    EMPTY
    0
    0 -> 1
    0 -> 1 -> 3
    0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3
```

Comment: *Would gladly appreciate any advice* -- Use the debugger that comes with your compiler.  Step through your program, watch variables, watch program flow, and see where the program deviates from what you expect.

Comment: I think you need to reread whatever tutorial or class notes you're using for not only linked lists, but code in-general. There has several problems, most of them unrelated to your question. Trying to understand a answer to the latter will be fruitless unless you get a firm grasp on the former.

Comment: @WhozCraig The functions do not have arguments because that's how the exercise was, the tutor also told me that I would need to use global variables. No need to be rude, just trying to find a solution in order to move on.

Comment: I'm not being rude, and every detail you just laid out here in comments belongs *in your question*, else it will be apt to criticism (it probably will anyway, but at least there is a *reason* outside of inexperience for oddity). And if this is being done with globals, `node *list` doesn't belong in `main()`, as it serves no purpose and isn't being used anyway.

Comment: @Scorpion -- So you're basically asking us how to do the wrong things to achieve a certain result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have design's problems.

First, remove the global variables:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node {
    int value;
    node* next;
};
node* list = NULL; // This
node* first_item = new node(); // And this
```

Every function should have an argument: The first node of the list. That's it. If you need the last element of the list, you should iterate to the end:

```
void print(node* list) { 

    node* iterator = list;
    if (iterator == NULL) {
        cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
    }
    while (iterator != NULL)
    {
        cout << iterator->value; // print node value
        if (iterator->next != NULL) {
            cout << " -> ";
        }
        iterator = iterator->next; // progress to next value
    }

    cout << endl;
}
void insert(node* first_item,int y) { // adds a new element y as the first element in the list

    //TODO Implement

}
void insert(int x, int y) {  // adds a new element y after the first occurrence of element x

    //TODO Implement
}

int main()
{
    node* list = NULL;

    print(list);
    insert(list,0);
    print(list);
    insert(0, 1); 

    print(list);
    insert(1, 3);
    print(list);
    insert(1, 2);
    print(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm not supposed to add the arguments in the functions or else I'm going to lose points.. This is the reason why I used global variables. Sorry for any troubles :(

Comment: @Scorpion sorry to hear that, because the *correct* way to do this is as tallied in this answer. An example [can be seen **here**](http://ideone.com/l44kca). Best of luck with that instructor. It sounds like you're going to need it.